# Concurrent writeJSON with gorilla websocket package

Tags: go, websocket, concurrency

Gorilla WebSocket doc mentions that
"Applications are responsible for ensuring that no more than one goroutine calls the write methods concurrently and that no more than one goroutine calls the read methods concurrently."

does this mean no two goroutines even though having different conn ptr can call write methods concurrently or this means that if we share the same conn ptr with different goroutines then we cannot write with that conn concurrently( which seems obvious though)..?

[gorilla doc link](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket#hdr-Concurrency)

Comment: The package would not be useful if the package restricted read operations to one connection at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each connection supports one concurrent reader and one concurrent writer.

Connections are independent of each other and share no state. It is typical that all connections in an application have a caller to a read method.

The documentation is explaining that a connection supports more concurrency than the default assumption of no concurrent access.

Comment: Sorry for repeating. Just for final confirmation.." so two goroutines having different connection ptr can call write methods concurrently?"

Comment: Yes, each of the two connections can have a writer.  Connections are independent of each other and do not share state.

Answer (score 0):

It is a basic, concurrency control requirement, that only one goroutine has a write lock. If there is only read locks, then any goroutine can read concurrently. But when a goroutine is writing, other goroutines should not read or write to the same value. If allowed, such situation can create many undesirable state, such as Dirty-Read problem. So you should always get an exclusive lock(write lock) using mutex while writing something concurrently.

Comment: So you mean here it does not depend upon conn ptr..?